# Ubuntu performance drop

Tags: performance

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14 and it seems im lagging. I started playing a 2d rpg game on steam and my whole pc is a bit sluggish. I read that I should use xubuntu or something. I'm on an intel HD processor with 3.12 GHz and 4gb ram. I'm running Ubuntu alone (no VM) what do I do to get this speed back up?

Comment: What was your former version? It is normal that newer versions are a bit slower than older ones...

Comment: @ByteCommander 13.10

Comment: If it is a CPU problem (means that CPU is the part of your machine that slows down the system most), could you run `top` in a terminal while you do some normal tasks. What are the processes that hog the most CPU percentage (except your applications)? If it is `compiz` you're better off with a lightweight DE like xfce. I recently changed to it and my system feels ways faster now.

Comment: fire fox and plugin-con+ are taking 30% each. Xorg is 13%. compiz is only 0.7

Comment: plugin-container belongs to firefox. Xorg is your graphics driver/render (not too sure, but graphics anyway). Try installing `xubuntu-desktop` and watch if it becomes faster.

Comment: @ByteCommander that says it's corrupted or something

Comment: @nubb "its corrupted or something" isn't a problem I'll be chasing and I doubt the quality of any answers you'll get with clarification like that. Although some of us have an uncanny psychic ability on occasion, it's rare. Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try Ubuntu MATE 14.04 LTS.

[image: Ubuntu MATE Screenshot]
Download it [here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/trusty/)

Comment: doesn't look to pretty. I really like the style of unity

Comment: Ok, then you may try Elementary OS. However, performance and beauty are mostly incompatible.